# How to check if jsp went to the controller in spring mvc and how to display list from controller to jsp?

Tags: java, sql, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc program running in tomcat.
It has a datatable that when a user clicks the button, certain values of the row where the button is clicked will be passed to the controller.

[It looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdUe8.png)

Here is how I create my datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#datatables').DataTable({
                "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
                "responsive": true,
                "scrollY": "550px",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "ajax": "smsSenders.json",
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"mData": "sender"},
                    {"mData": "content"},
                    {"mData": "receiveTime"},
                    {"mData": "portId",
                        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd,oData) {
                            $(nTd).html("<i class='ti-pencil-alt btn btn-simple btn-assign btn-icon' data-toggle='modal' data-mode='asign'></i>\n\n\
                            <i class='ti-comment-alt btn btn-simple btn-reply btn-icon' data-target='#conversationModal' data-toggle='modal' data-mode='conversation'></i>\
                         ");
                        }
                    }
                ],
                language: {
                    "search": "_INPUT_",
                    searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
                }

            });

        demo.initCirclePercentage();
```

Here is how I pass the certain values of the row where the button is clicked.

```
$('#datatables tbody').on( 'click', '.btn-reply', function () {
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
            var data = $('#datatables').DataTable().row(currentRow).data();
            var sender = data['sender'];
            var smsc = data['smsc'];
            alert(sender + "-----------------"+smsc);
            $.ajax({
                   url:'dashboard',
                   data: {
                    "sender": sender,
                    "smsc": smsc
                   },
                   success: function(){
                       alert("success");
                   },
                   error: function(){
                       alert("error");
                   },
                   type: 'POST'
                });
            });
```

Here is my controller class.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/dashboard"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String conversationList(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "sender", required = true) String sender, 
        @RequestParam(value = "smsc", required = true) String smsc, HttpServletRequest request,
        @ModelAttribute("conversationList") ConversationMessages conversationMessage) throws Exception{
    LOGGER.debug("sender==================================="+sender);

    List<ConversationMessages> conversationList = dashboardService.getConversationList(sender,smsc);
    model.addAttribute("conversationList",conversationList);
    LOGGER.debug("this is conversation============================="+conversationList);

    return "dashboard";    
}
```

I don't know if what I'm doing here is correct. But it doesn't give any error in the browser console and server log.

Do I need to use the @ModelAttribute in my controller?

Here is my xml mapper

```
<resultMap id="conversationList" type="com.beneco.cwms.domain.dashboard.ConversationMessages">
    <result property="messageId" column="message_id"/>
    <result property="sender" column="sender"/>
    <result property="smsc" column="smsc"/>        
    <result property="portId" column="port_id"/>
    <result property="content" column="content"/>
    <result property="receiveTime" column="receive_time"/>
    <result property="hasRead" column="has_read"/>
    <result property="isAssignedToTicket" column="is_assigned_to_ticket"/> 
</resultMap>

<select id="getConversationList" parameterType="map" resultMap="conversationList">

    SELECT * FROM (SELECT*FROM SMS_MESSAGES WHERE SENDER = #{sender} and SMSC = #{smsc} and IS_ASSIGNED_TO_TICKET is null 
        UNION
    SELECT * FROM SMS_REPLY WHERE SMSC = #{sender} and SENDER = #{smsc} and IS_ASSIGNED_TO_TICKET is null) order by RECEIVE_TIME;

</select>
```

Here is my service implementation class.

```
public class DashboardServiceImpl implements DashboardService{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SmsServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private DashboardMapper dashboardmapper;

    @Override
    public List<ConversationMessages> getConversationList(String sender, String smsc) {
        LOGGER.debug(dashboardmapper.getConversationList(sender,smsc) + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        return dashboardmapper.getConversationList(sender,smsc);
    }
}
```

Here is how I display the list in my jsp

```
<div class="modal fade" id="conversationModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Conversation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <c:forEach items="${conversationList}" var="user">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Sender: ${sender}</label>
                            <label>Content: ${sender}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="saveAddress">Send</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way for the controller to return a modal inside a page instead of the page itself?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. The user clicks the button.
2. Values where the button is clicked will be passed to the controller.
3. A query will be executed based on the values passed.
4. Controller will return to the same page but a modal showing the query results.

I have this showing in my tomcat.

> WebAccessDeniedHandler:35 handle - User: admin attempted to access the
>   protected URL: /cwms/dashboard

TIA!

Comment: additional question: How do I check if the program is going to the controller after the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `@ModelAttribute` since you don't pass any model, `@RequestParam` is enough. As you mention the alert is working inside the ajax and the data doesn't pass to the controller, I think, you are using just absolute path in the ajax URL which is no longer available, so better you should use relative path. Even Absolute path is fine, if you properly define it.

The following code shows a relative path,

```
<script>
   <c:url value = "/dashboard" var="dbURL"/> //hope you don't have a parent mapping like ..:8080/myProject/index/dashboard
   //other codes
   $.ajax({
   url : "${dbURL}"
   //codes
})
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @varman, I've already tried to do this. Still, It doesn't work. I'm actually finding another way to pass the variables to the controller. Any ideas on how I should do it? I've also tried to pass the variables through url but it still wont go to the controller. 

`Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            LOGGER.warn("User: " + auth.getName() + " attempted to access the protected URL: " + request.getRequestURI());
        }
`
I think this is preventing it to go to the controller and I don't know why.

Comment: You are using spring security, and are you using roles fro users?

Comment: If it is, you have to enable the url to the user, in `SecurityConfiguration` class, you have to allow user to use the url like `antMatchers("/dashboard").access("hasRole('SYSTEM_ADMIN')")`. refer this https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: I really can't make this work. I've tried to use another method to pass the variable. Right now I'm trying to pass it through url. but it's saying undefined.

Comment: Update your codes of SecurityConfigure, will try to help you

Comment: Hi @varman, I don't think the codes of the SecurityConfigure needs to be updated because other modules are working.

Comment: Fine, If you can't update it, let me know the dashboard url is allowed to the user? Otherwise allow it. And submit a form manually to the controller and check whether form is working or not